# error on multipe variables in csv import

Tags: excel, csv, vba

after learning VBE basics with a book I finally tried to build a macro for opening a csv file, let it be put in an excell sheet, save as the csvname and redo untill all are done.

I ran into a problem with the line after 'input csv file. It gives a error number 13, I have absolutly no clue how to fix it. I currently think that u can't put in variables there? Am I right? Is there any solution?

Please give an example how to fix this

```
Sub CSVnaarxlsx()
    'On Error Resume Next
    'declareer variabelen
    Dim strpath As String
    Dim fmn As Integer
    Dim lmn As Integer
    Dim csvname As String
    'active workbook pathway
    strpath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    'ask user for first and last number
    fmn = InputBox("first mouse number")
    lmn = InputBox("last mouse number")
    'einde sub if inputbox is empty
    'If fmn = "" Then
    'MsgBox "No first mouse number"
    'Exit Sub
    'End If
    'If lmn = "" Then
    'MsgBox "No Last mouse number"
    'Exit Sub
    'End If

'assign variables

'loop al de files
 For fmn = fmn To (lmn + 1)
 csvname = "m" & fmn
 'input of csv file
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;strpath & " / " & csvname" & ".csv""" _
        , Destination:=Range("sheet1!$A$1"))
        .Name = csvname
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 _
        , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1)
        .TextFileDecimalSeparator = "."
        .TextFileThousandsSeparator = ","
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    End With
Call CsvToXlsx(ByVal csvname, strpath)
Next fmn

End Sub

Sub CsvToXlsx(ByVal csvname, strpath)
ChDir (strpath & "/verwerkt")
csvname = csvname & .xlsx
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=csvname, FileFormat:=51
End Sub
```

Comment: If an answer suits you, please accept it at your convenience. Here's a super-quick explanation in the form of a screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Answer (score 0):

The routine below prompts the user to select CSVs and saves them all as .xlsx files into the same directory as the host workbook. I added lots of comments to explain everything that was happening -- hope this helps!

```
Option Explicit
Sub OpenCSVFiles()

Dim Path As String
Dim TargetFiles As FileDialog
Dim Index As Long
Dim CSVBook As Workbook

'prompt user to select CSV files
Set TargetFiles = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With TargetFiles
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Title = "Select CSV files:"
    .ButtonName = ""
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add ".csv files", "*.csv"
    .Show
End With

'check to see if the user clicked cancel, if so exit
If TargetFiles.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

'loop through the selected files
For Index = 1 To TargetFiles.SelectedItems.Count

    'open the CSV
    Set CSVBook = Workbooks.Open(TargetFiles.SelectedItems(Index))

    'extract the file path and file name
    Path = CSVBook.FullName
    Path = Left(Path, Len(Path) - 4) '<~ remove the .csv extension

    'save as an xlsx file, no alerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    CSVBook.SaveAs Filename:=Path, FileFormat:=51 '<~ .xlsx = 51 on Windows
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'close the CSV and repeat
    CSVBook.Close False

Next Index

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much I couldn't have found this myself. It is a totally different code I created. I will try to understand what it does, and learn a lot from it. I now only still need to implement that there is a commaseparator.

Comment: @BtotheE very glad to hear it. This is different, as I've never used `QueryTables` before, but it should do the trick. If this answer suits you, please accept it at your convenience. Here's a super-quick explanation in the form of a screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Comment: I used the macro recorder to create that part of macro and thought that it was able to add some variables for making a loop. After a while I noticed it didn't.

Comment: The macro recorder is great @BtotheE, but it converting what you learn from using it into loops can be challenging

Comment: I have found what causes the error, you need to replace 
ith ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;strpath & " / " & csvname" & ".csv""" _
        , Destination:=Range("sheet1!$A$1"))
with
ith ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" + strpath & "\" & csvname & ".csv",  _
        Destination:=Range("sheet1!$A$1"))

When i run the macro now he will do the loop and save correctly but he won't put the csvdata in the saved excelfile

Comment: Bummer @BtotheE, it looks like using the `FileDialog` object strategy (as I did above) might be the best fit for your situation then

Comment: It could be but the data in the csvfile is separated by a comma, so unless I can build this in, there is not much interest because in the second sheet i use a lot of formulas reffering to cells in sheet 1 to do a lot of dataselecting for me... So all we need is another person helping us brainstorm

Comment: Hey @BtotheE, copying data from the CSV to an already-existing workbook can easily be done. I would recommend opening another question that more explicitly explains your already-existing workbook. Also, I have written a response about combining files into a single "master" file here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23597511/merge-multiple-excel-workbooks-into-single-masterlist/23601463#23601463